# How to maintain state of an app after a refresh, AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to make a basic social networking application following [Write Modern Web Apps with the MEAN Stack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133930157) book.

The end result should be: https://mean-sample.herokuapp.com/

I got through to getting user accounts set up, having a user log in and create a personalized post. But as soon as I refresh, the user gets logged out.

What am I doing wrong? And how do I fix this?

Comment: you need to maintain a token in local-storage if you want to persist token across the session...

Answer (score 0):

In the client side we cant maintain the session, we need the server support to it. There are many ways to maintain the session
1 Token based, for each request to the server, the server will check whether token exists or not.
2 We can store in the localstorage while refresh the rootscope will be, at that time we can take from local store and populate the page objects.

Maintaining in server side is secured and advisable.

Answer (score 0):

use localstorage, it will help you in maintaining the session and also store user details temporarily.

Refer this for more details

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage